# Toggle excerpt and content onclick - Wordpress - php string

Tags: php, wordpress, toggle

I am altering an wordpress theme to display my blog posts and I've been trying to add a toggle between excerpt and content when clicking on 'Read More'.
I have been unsuccessful on many attempts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    $post_data = "<article class='post style-2$sticky_class'>";
    $post_data.= "<div class='blog-item'>";
    $post_data .= "<header class='col-md-4 col-xs-12 no-padding'>";
    if(is_sticky(get_the_ID()) && strlen(anps_header_media(get_the_ID(), $image_class)) > 0 ) {
    $post_data .= "<div class='absolute stickymark'><div class='triangle-topleft hovercolor'></div><i class='nav_background_color fa fa-thumb-tack'></i></div>";
    }
    $post_data .= "<a href='".get_permalink()."'>".anps_header_media(get_the_ID(), $image_class)."<div class='cat_banner'>".$cat_name."</div></a>";
    $post_data .= "</header>";

    $post_data.= "<div class='archive_blog_info col-md-8'>";

    if (is_sticky(get_the_ID()) && strlen(anps_header_media(get_the_ID(), $image_class)) < 1 ) {
    $post_data .= "<a href='".get_permalink()."' title='".get_the_title()."'><h1><i class='fa fa-thumb-tack hovercolor'></i>&nbsp;".get_the_title()."</h1></a>";
    $post_data .= "<h1>".get_the_date()."</h1>";
     }
    else {
        $post_data .= "<a href='".get_permalink()."' title='".get_the_title()."'><h1>".get_the_title()."</h1></a>";
    }

    $post_data .= "<div class='post-excerpt'>".$excerpt_text."</div>";
    $post_data .= "<div class='post-content'>".$content_text."</div>";
    $post_data .= '<a class="btn btn-sm style-4 read" href="">'.__("Read more", 'accounting').'</a>';
    $post_data .= '<a class="btn btn-sm style-4 read-less" href="">'.__("Read less", 'accounting').'</a>';
    $post_data .= '<a class="news_link btn btn-sm style-4" style="float:right!important;" href="/category/'.$cat_name.'/">'.__("More ".$cat_name." articles >>", 'accounting').'</a>';
    $post_data .= "</div>";
    $post_data .='</div>';

$post_data .= "</article>"; 
echo $post_data;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript to handle the click events of read more or read less. I prefer jquery. I have prepared a fiddle.

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/at36xwa8/4/]
```